# Develop games for windows mobile

Tags: windows-mobile

Does anybody know a good place to find things about game development for windows mobile?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you will require is the [Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windowsmobile/bb264337.aspx) and [Startup kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb264330.aspx). This link is for .Net for Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Rob Miles did a [series](http://www.robmiles.com/mobile-game-development/) of webcasts on game programming on Windows Mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check these [video from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/bb495180.aspx) that show you basic coding (not game but can help you) on Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can register as a developer in the App Hub (http://create.msdn.com/en-US/) and download all relevant software from there. 
If you have a WF7 device and you want to test your software on it, you would need to unlock it for development purposes. 
you can find a guide to do that in the app hub.
They seem to have a very good documentation on it, plus it is c# (which is well known and well documented).

Good luck.